# Database conversion from latin1 to utf8mb4, what about indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding, collation, modx

I noticed that my MODX database still uses latin1 character set in the database and in its tables. I would like to convert them to utf8mb4 and update collations accordingly.

Not totally sure how I should do this. Is this correct?

- I alter every table to use utf8mb4 and utf8_unicode_ci?
- I update the default character set and collation of the database.

Are indexes updated automatically? Is there something else I should be aware of?

A bonus question: what would be the most suitable latest utf8_unicode collation? Western languages should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the default character sets of a table or a schema does not change the data in the column itself, it only changes the default to apply the next time you add a table or add a column to a table.

To convert current data, alter one table at a time:

```
ALTER TABLE <name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

The collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci is faster than earlier collations (at least according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)), and it's the most current and accurate. This collation requires MySQL 8.0.

The most current collation in MySQL 5.7 is utf8_unicode_520_ci.

A table-conversion like this rebuilds the indexes, so there's nothing else you need to do.

Comment: 5.7 also has utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci .

Comment: This provides a way to build all the alters needed:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes